# Which episode is the 'tick tick boom' image captured from?

Tags: lost-girl

I was browsing around on the internet recently, as you do, and came across this image, which is a picture of Kenzi from Lost Girl;

[image: Tick Tick... Booooom]

To save me from watching both series of Lost Girl again to find this episode, does anybody know which episode this image has been captured from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Season 2, Episode 16, 'School's Out'